# Folders in Gitlab?

Tags: directory, gitlab

I am trying to create folders in Gitlab through the web interface. I was able to see some [repositories](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master)  with folders. I could not find any option to create such folders. How are such folders created?

Comment: It would be possible in Github see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36411/create-a-folder-in-github-via-the-web-interface but not in Gitlab (It just creates file from basename)

Comment: But this repository on Gitlab has folders https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master

Comment: Its because they have uploaded folders from local repo to remote

Answer (score 1):

If you specified a path for a file, Gitlab will create directories if they not exists.
For example, if you add a file named `dir1/dir2/test.md`, Gitlab create two nested directories with `test.md` inside.